# Why descriptors (in Python) cannot be inserted (placed) in ALREADY initialized object?

Tags: python, oop, class, object, descriptor

In a process of coding I have been faced with the need to change behavior of object's property (but NOT a class property). And I found that already initialized object cannot be patched with descriptor. So why?

code examples

```
class A(object):
    pass

class D(object):
    def __init__(self, fget=None, fset=None, fdel=None, doc=None):
        pass
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        return 5

A.x = D()
A.x
Out[12]: 5 # work!
a = A()
a.y = D()
a.y
Out[14]: <__main__.D at 0x13a8d90> # not work!
```

Comment: Descriptors are for classes, and `a` is not a class.  How about just using `a.y = 5`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#invoking-descriptors).

> For objects, the machinery is in `object.__getattribute__()` which transforms `b.x` into `type(b).__dict__['x'].__get__(b, type(b))`.

That is, the attribute lookup on an *instance* (`b`) is converted into a descriptor call on the *class* (`type(b)`).  Descriptors operate at the class level.

As for why this is true, it's because descriptors are basically a way to do method-like work (i.e., call a method) on attribute lookup.  And methods are essentially class-level behavior: you generally define the methods you want on a class, and you don't add extra methods to individual instances.  Doing descriptor lookup on an instance would be like defining a method on an instance.

Now, it is possible to assign new methods to instances, and it's also possible to get descriptors to work on instances of a particular class.  You just have to do extra work.  As the documentation quote above says, the machinery is in `object.__getattribute__`, so you can override it by defining a custom `__getattribute__` on your class:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        myDict = object.__getattribute__(self, '__dict__')
        if attr in myDict and hasattr(myDict[attr], '__get__'):
            return myDict[attr].__get__(self, type(self))
        else:
            return super(Foo, self).__getattribute__(attr)

class D(object):
    def __init__(self, fget=None, fset=None, fdel=None, doc=None):
        pass
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        return 5
```

And then:

```
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.x = D()
>>> f.x
5
```

So if you feel the need to do this, you can make it happen.  It's just not the default behavior, simply because it's not what descriptors were designed to do.